# Using mod_rewrite to re-order part of a url path alphabetically

Tags: mod-rewrite, path, django-views, directory, alphabetical

Any help using mod_rewrite to re-order part of a url path alphabetically would be greatly appreciated.

The Problem: I need any path parameters after **mysite.com/check/** to be re-ordered alphabetically and ideally converted to lower case.

For example:

mysite.com/check/**dog/Cat/rat**

would become:

mysite.com/check/**cat/dog/rat**

Please note that the length of path parameters *will* vary so re-ordering is only required when there is more then one.

I'm thinking I need to somehow capture the string after **check/**, split/explode it into an array/list of some sort, re-order it then add it back to the url. Problem is I'm not sure this is even possible with mod_rewrite as so far my googling hasn't turned up much.

This is for a django (python) based project. The views.py handles the path parameters like so.

```
def check(request, *args):
    for arg in args:
        arg = arg.split('/')
        arg = list(set(arg)) # Remove Duplicates
        arg.sort()
        for a in arg:
            a = a.lower()
            ...
```

Please help you mod_rewrite experts!

Answer (score 0):

You can have mod_rewrite [call external program](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritemap) (with `MapType` set to `prg`). It can be e.g. python script with logic copied from django.

Comment: Ah sweet! Thanks @eudoxos  Looks like that might be what I am after. I will have a look into it and post back how I get on. Cheers, D.